# Error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity

I' m trying to delete a items of a table. This table have a related with another table.

```
try
{
    db.OrganizationalUnitType.Remove(SelectedUnitType);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //TODO CODE FOR EXCEPTION
}
```

I have a item(item1) that not have any related with another items, when i run application i can delete this item(item1), but when I'm trying to delete another item(item2) that have related i get error,after this action when i select item1 and want to delete this get this error, but if i close the application and run again i can delete this item !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem before and select new object solve my problem like below , 'unitID' is the primary key of item you want to delete , hope it helps you too

```
try
  {
    var NewSelectedUnitType = db.OrganizationalUnitType.SingleOrDefault(p=>p.ID == unitID);
    db.OrganizationalUnitType.Remove(NewSelectedUnitType);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
  {
     ..
  }
```